# How to Rename Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

How to rename bunch of files in windows using powershell.
Example of filenames:

```
Image001 L@ter
Image002 L@ter
```

I have tried these two commands ,

```
get-childitem * | ForEach { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.name $_.name.Replace("L@ter","")}
get-childitem * | ForEach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("L@ter","") }
```

I expect the output to be as Image001,Image002

Answer (score 0):

Your question says to rename, but your code samples are using the `Move-Item` command. I am going to assume you were unsure hot to rename them correctly as you weren't actually moving them.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\" -File | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.Name -replace '\s*(l@ster)')"
}
```

The `\s*` will match any whitespace before your main capturing group

The `(l@ster)` is the main capture group, it looks for that exact phrase and will match it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent category of question.  I like to use rename-item with a scriptblock.  Take off the -whatif if it looks right.  I'm assuming you don't want the space at the end of the names.

```powershell
ls '* l@ter' | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace ' l@ter' } -whatif
```

Answer (score 0):

first, some small details about your commands:

```
get-childitem * | ForEach { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.name $_.name.Replace("L@ter","")}
```

**LiteralPath** is meant to be used used exactly as it is typed. So I would use it with

**$*.FullName*** instead of **$.name** if I must use strange paths (like network shares).

second: 
In the get-help for both **move-item** and **rename-item** I can see that the **-path** parameter :

```
Required?                    true
Position?                    0
Default value                None
Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
```

which means that we can pipe a collection of objects into it and the rename cmdlet will automatically pass through the collection :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\tests\' -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.name -replace ' l@ter') -Force -WhatIf
```

I have made this reply redundant for Drew's and Js2010's replys, but, as I am a beginner in powershell, I find easier to understand the answers with full commands.